# Elasticsearch search based on term position and fuzzy

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am a beginner in Elasticsearch and I try to combine a query with term position and fuzzy and the results are not what I expected.

I tried this query

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                            {
                                "query_string": {
                                    "query": "douille~ raccordment~",
                                    "fields": [
                                        "name^10"
                                    ],
                                    "default_operator": "AND",
                                    "fuzziness": "AUTO:10,20"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "should": [
                            {
                                "span_first": {
                                    "match": {
                                        "span_multi": {
                                            "match": {
                                                "fuzzy": {
                                                    "name": {
                                                        "value": "douille",
                                                        "fuzziness": "AUTO"
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "end": 1
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "span_first": {
                                    "match": {
                                        "span_multi": {
                                            "match": {
                                                "fuzzy": {
                                                    "name": {
                                                        "value": "douille",
                                                        "fuzziness": "AUTO"
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "end": 2
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

The word "raccordment" isn't spelled well (in French). The right word is "raccordement". I have a product "Douille Raccordement" in my index and products with "Douille" without "Raccordement" in the name but not in the first position in my index. When I try the query, I have no result.

My aim is to have this kind of results with the search "douille raccordment" (based on term position, with or without misspell):

- Douille Raccordement
- Douille 1
- 10 Douilles
- Raccordement 1
- Raccordement 2

I use Elasticsearch 7.

Do you know why?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

For this data in your question. This query can help you:

```
POST idx_test/_bulk
{"index":{}}
{"name": "Douille Raccordement"}
{"index":{}}
{"name": "Douille 1"}
{"index":{}}
{"name": "10 Douilles"}
{"index":{}}
{"name": "Raccordement 1"}
{"index":{}}
{"name": "Raccordement 2"}

GET idx_test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": {
        "query": "douille raccordment",
        "fuzziness": "AUTO"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "hits" : {
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "Douille Raccordement"
        }
      },
      {
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "Douille 1"
        }
      },
      {
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "10 Douilles"
        }
      },
      {
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "Raccordement 1"
        }
      },
      {
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "Raccordement 2"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean instead of query_string?
{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"bool":{"must":[{"match":{"name":{"query":"douille raccordment","fuzziness":"AUTO"}}}]}}]}}}

Comment: This query works for documents in your question. Maybe work in your real Index.